# eglCreateWindowSurface: native_window_api_connect failed

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I have a problem that occours only with the latest Samsung Galaxy series *when android:hardwareAccelerated is set to false into manifest file*

As far as i know (tried by myself) it happens on Galaxy S9, J6 and Note 8 but not on Galaxy S8 for example. Other phones seem not affected at all.

The problem is that i got a GLSurfaceView that shows nothing (black screen) but if i switch between activities, it start to work again, i guess because it renews the View with no errors.

This is the suspect log lines i've found

```
01-13 14:39:47.813 25013 25080 E libEGL  : eglCreateWindowSurface: native_window_api_connect (win=0xc166b808) failed (0xffffffed) (already connected to another API?)
01-13 14:39:47.813 25013 25080 E libEGL  : eglCreateWindowSurface:679 error 3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
```

and these are the crucial part of my code:

```
GLSurf glsurf;

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // stop
    if (glsurf != null) {
        glsurf.onPause();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (glsurf != null)
        glsurf.onResume();
}

public class GLSurf extends GLSurfaceView {

    public GLSurf(Context context) {
        super(context);

        /* Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context. */
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);

        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        mRenderer = new GLRenderer(context);
        setRenderer(mRenderer);

        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }
}

public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {

    GLRenderer(Context c){
        // does nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

        // i've copied it but it's not even reached

        // call jni function updating the single texture filling the screen
        nativeGLRender();

        // Draw the triangles
        GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length,
                GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

        // We need to know the current width and height.
        mScreenWidth = width;
        mScreenHeight = height;

        // Redo the Viewport.
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, (int)mScreenWidth, (int)mScreenHeight);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

        // Set the clear color to black
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);
    }

}
```

Some info more:

the EGL_BAD_ALLOC occours always after this sequence of events with meaningful (at least i think) logs

```
onCreate
onResume
onPause

GLSurfaceView: Warning, !readyToDraw() but waiting for draw finished! Early reporting draw finished.

onResume 

libEGL  : eglCreateWindowSurface: native_window_api_connect (win=0xc166b808) failed (0xffffffed) (already connected to another API?)
libEGL  : eglCreateWindowSurface:679 error 3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)

onPause
onStop
onDestroy
onCreate 
onResume
onSurfaceCreated

        : NULL == surf->write_back_color_buffer
        : NULL == surf->write_back_color_buffer
GLThread: eglSwapBuffers failed: EGL_BAD_SURFACE

... black screen ...
```

Please note that above events occour with no user interaction and in a span of 1-2 seconds. Any idea about what's going on?

For completion of infos, the following is the sequence of a working phone (e.g. my nexus 6)

```
onCreate
onResume
onSurfaceCreated
... working screen
```

**Edit Jan 16th:**

New informations about the issue:

- When the app starts for the first time, it works
- Never work on the next tries
- It works if put in background and restored
- The error never happen if i put android:hardwareAccelerated to true (but i cannot turn it on for other reasons)

**Edit Jan 18th**

- I forgot to mention that the issue occours only if android:hardwareAccelerated is set to false

**I ALSO FOUND THE REASON OF THE BUG**

Don't know why, but i just changed this part of code

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
}
```

with this

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

and everything went ok. A bug in Samsung drivers? Maybe...

I hope this could be useful for somebody

Answer (score 2):

> eglCreateWindowSurface: native_window_api_connect failed **Any idea
>   about what's going on**?

## The problem viewed from logcat perspective

The called function from [eglApi.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/nougat-release/opengl/libs/EGL/eglApi.cpp#459) is:

```
/*
 * native_window_api_connect(..., int api)
 * connects an API to this window. only one API can be connected at a time.
 * Returns -EINVAL if for some reason the window cannot be connected, which
 * can happen if it's connected to some other API.
 */
static inline int native_window_api_connect(
        struct ANativeWindow* window, int api)
{
    return window->perform(window, NATIVE_WINDOW_API_CONNECT, api);
}
```

Here is a comment block from the `WindowSurface.recreate()` from [WindowSurface.java](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/MediaCodec/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mcxiaoke/media/av/WindowSurface.java) method that says:

```
/*
 * If the previous EGLSurface isn't fully destroyed, e.g. it's still current on a
 * context somewhere, the create call will fail with complaints from the Surface
 * about already being connected.
*/
```

## Related problem

[Opengls eglCreateWindowSurface GL Error EGL_BAD_ALLOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312209/opengls-eglcreatewindowsurface-gl-error-egl-bad-alloc)
 from [Jitesh Dalsaniya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2078099/jitesh-dalsaniya):

> I solved error GL Error EGL_BAD_ALLOC. This error occurs due to I am
>   not handling Renderer properly with activity life cycle.
>
> **Activity Life-cycle**
>
> A `GLSurfaceView` **must** be notified when to **pause** and
>   **resume** rendering. `GLSurfaceView` clients are required to call `onPause()` when the activity stops and `onResume()` when the activity
>   starts. These calls allow `GLSurfaceView` to pause and resume the
>   rendering thread, and also allow `GLSurfaceView` to release and
>   recreate the `OpenGL` display.

**EGL Context Lost**

> There are situations where the `EGL` rendering context will be lost.
>   This typically happens when device wakes up after going to sleep. When
>   the `EGL` context is lost, all `OpenGL` resources (such as textures)
>   that are associated with that `context` will be automatically deleted.
>   In order to keep rendering correctly, a renderer must recreate any
>   lost resources that it still needs. The `onSurfaceCreated`(GL10,
>   EGLConfig) method is a convenient place to do this.

## [Workaround-to-losing-the-opengl-context-when-android-pauses](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12629/workaround-to-losing-the-opengl-context-when-android-pauses)

So your `Activity's` `onPause()` should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    glsurf.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    super.onPause();
    ...
}
```

And you restore your `GLSurfaceView` to the hierarchy **not from** `onResume()` but from `onWindowFocusChanged()` :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus && glsurf.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
         glsurf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    ...
}
```

## Other things to try

1. You'd need to debug to figure out why it's unhappy.
2. Try use `OpenglView` Visible always and `startPreview` when you get permissions. An invisible holder is not valid for opengl and this could cause your crash.
3. Bad release of Opengl ?
4. Handle `onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged` in `TextureViewGLActivity` ?
5. `EGL_BAD_ALLOC` and `eglSwapBuffers failed:` `EGL_BAD_SURFACE` is a big clue...
6. `!readyToDraw()` delete and recreate the Surface ?

## Further

Observation:

> The error never happen if I put `android:hardwareAccelerated` to true
>
> Hardware acceleration is ***enabled*** by default if your `Target API` level
>   `is >=14`, but can also be explicitly enabled (at the Application **or** Activity level).

## Document Links

[GLSurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView), [GLSurfaceView.Renderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer), [hardware-acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel)

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to mention that the issue occours when hardwareAccelerated is false

Comment: @Davide Berra Yes I saw that and understood, I can look at what happens with hardwareAccelerated is false (and why hardwareAccelerated is true gives no problem), but do you really want/need it to be false ? Are you happy now (or do you still have problems)?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `glsurf.setVisibility(View.GONE)` in `onPause()` works for my app, but it won't work when I call `glsurf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in `onWindowFocusChanged()`.

It works for me when I call `glsurf.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` in `onResume()`.